# Cannot access base class properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack-2, phaser-framework, typescript2.0

I've got a rather strange problem. I'm extending a class, and for some reason none of the extended class's properties or methods are accessible. Here's my class:

```
import "pixi";
import "p2";
import Phaser from "phaser";

export class MyGameState extends Phaser.State {
    // More stuff [...]
    create() {
        this.game.add.sprite(400, 300, "./assets/paddle.png");
    }
}
```

This actually does seem to successfully compile and run, but outputs an error about how it can't access `game` in `this.game`:

`ERROR in ./src/my-game/MyGameState.ts
(17,14): error TS2339: Property 'game' does not exist on type 'MyGameState'.`

Intellij is also confused. It seems to recognize that `create()` is overriding a base class function, but also thinks `game` doesn't exist.

It's perfectly happy to access `game` off of `Phaser.State` inside that class, though, as long as it's not the extended version. So this compiles and works fine:

```
const workingState = new Phaser.State();
workingState.game.boot();
```

Here's a foreshortened version of the class in `phaser.d.ts` I'm extending:

```
declare module "phaser-ce" {
    export = Phaser;
}

declare class Phaser {
    class State {
        game: Phaser.Game;
        create(): void;
    }
}
```

And the horribly hairy configuration I've got to get Phaser working with Typescript this well ...

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "MyGame",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.12",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.4",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "tslint": "^5.5.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "phaser-ce": "^2.8.1",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/"
  ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin')

// Phaser webpack config
var phaserModule = path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/phaser-ce/')
var phaser = path.join(phaserModule, 'build/custom/phaser-split.js')
var pixi = path.join(phaserModule, 'build/custom/pixi.js')
var p2 = path.join(phaserModule, 'build/custom/p2.js')

var definePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                                                __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.BUILD_DEV || 'true'))
                                            })

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main2.ts')
        ],
        vendor: ['pixi', 'p2', 'phaser', 'webfontloader']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        pathinfo: true,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: './dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    watch: true,
    plugins: [
        definePlugin,
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
            {name: 'vendor'/* chunkName= */, filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'/* filename= */}),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
                                  host: process.env.IP || 'localhost',
                                  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
                                  server: {
                                      baseDir: ['./', './build']
                                  }
                              })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.ts$/, enforce: 'pre', loader: 'tslint-loader', options: {emitErrors: true, failOnHint: true}},
            {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader'},
            {test: /pixi\.js/, use: ['expose-loader?PIXI']},
            {test: /phaser-split\.js$/, use: ['expose-loader?Phaser']},
            {test: /p2\.js/, use: ['expose-loader?p2']},
            {enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader"}
        ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'phaser': phaser,
            'pixi': pixi,
            'p2': p2
        },
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the fancy combined phaser my webpack config creates must be broken in some way shape or form.

I discovered I could prevent the typescript error by importing phaser in a different way:

```
import * as Phaser from "phaser-ce";
```

When imported this way I do not get errors and can use the members of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a specific answer for Phaser, but more a general "where to start" answer.

Step one is, check out `this`:

```
export class MyGameState extends Phaser.State {
    // More stuff [...]
    create() {
        console.log(this);
        this.game.add.sprite(400, 300, "./assets/paddle.png");
    }
}
```

One of the most common gotcas in TypeScript (and JavaScript) is that `this` is not what you expect. This happens in TypeScript when a class method is invoked in a different context, such as an event.

If you find that `this` is an element, or some other context, you can probably solve the problem with a fat-arrow (`=>`), [which preserves the lexical scope](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/04/typescript-scope-responsibility/).

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. Hadn't thought of that, but it seems it isn't the issue. I can access other methods of the class, just not the base class methods.